# C#: Clear variables before long delay to clear up memory

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm working on an import routine in C# which transfers dozens of gigabytes in multiple threads. I'm using `SemaphoreSlim` as a limiter. My code consists of two parts, A (gathering data) and B (storing data to DB). Both have their own limiters. The issue is, that the delay for part B can be rather long. So I want to free up memory before the delay. Does it make sense to assign those variables `null` before waiting for the semaphore?

Here's an abstracted form of my code:

```cs
private static async Task DoSmeStuff(MyParameters params, SemaphoreSlim dbLimiter, SemaphoreSlim apiLimiter)
{
    using DatabaseEntities db = new();

    Task<RetObj1> dbTask = GetDataFromDb(params, db, dbLimiter);
    Task<RetObj2> apiTask = GetDataFromApi(params, apiLimiter);

    await Task.WhenAll(dbTask, apiTask);

    RetObj1 dbResult= dbTask.Result;
    RetObj2 apiResult = apiTask.Result;

    // Does that make sense?
    dbTask = null;
    apiTask = null;

    ApplyChanges(db, dbResult, apiResult);

    // Does that make sense?
    dbResult = null;
    apiResult = null;

    try
    {
        // This can take a few minutes
        await dbLimiter.WaitAsync();

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        dbLimiter.Release();
    }
}
```

Before the dbLimiter provides a free slot, some minutes can pass. Because I'm transferring a lot of data, the memory usage of my import routine can go as high as 12GB, because it keeps all those then-unnecessary results in memory.

So, in this particular case, would it work to free up memory by assigning `null` to all those objects I don't use anymore? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Better to put using block around section which will dispose and call garbage collector :  using{DatabaseEntities db = new();    .... RetObj2 apiResult = apiTask.Result;}

Comment: The Result objects are **not** disposable.

Comment: Try to put `GC.Collect()` after your `null` assignments and monitor the memory to check if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes this will make a difference since the memory is freed to be reused by other threads if needed. However the bigger problem here is that your method is violating the SOLID principle, particularly the Single responsibility principle. You should refactor this method into 2: ApplyChanges and the second part that is saving the changes. That way, when the first part is done, those 2 variables will fall out of scope and you don't need to set them to null.

Comment: @funatparties I see. I solved it with some internal scopes.